# How to replace the values from next row if values doesn't match in dataframe join

Tags: python, pandas

I am having two dataframe and I am trying to join them on a key and at certain row doesn't have matching row so I am using `bfill` method but its filling the values from the output I want to fill it the next value from the other dataframe.

df1:

```
rcd_date  
2012-01-30
2012-02-29
2012-03-30
2012-04-30
```

df2:

```
nav_date   mfv_gross
2012-01-30 10.00
2012-01-31 10.00
2012-02-01 10.17
2012-02-06 10.50
2012-02-29 11.06
2012-03-31 10.68
2012-04-01 10.76
2012-04-28  10.87
2012-04-29  10.94
2012-04-30  10.97
```

my code :

```
joined = cash_df.set_index('rcd_date').join(nav_data.set_index('nav_date')).fillna(method='bfill')
```

output:

```
rcd_date    mfv_gross
2012-01-30  10.00
2012-02-29  11.06
2012-03-30  10.97
2012-04-30  10.97
```

desired output:

```
rcd_date    mfv_gross
2012-01-30  10.00
2012-02-29  11.06
2012-03-30  10.68
2012-04-30  10.97
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with method `'bfill'` by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) created by min and max dates of `df1['rcd_date']`:

```
rng = pd.date_range(df1['rcd_date'].min(), df1['rcd_date'].max())
df2 = df2.set_index('nav_date').reindex(rng, method='bfill')
df = df1.set_index('rcd_date').join(df2)
print (df)
            mfv_gross
rcd_date             
2012-01-30      10.00
2012-02-29      10.78
2012-03-30      10.68
2012-04-30      10.97
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for the quick help. When I am trying with a large dataframe which I am reading from a text file its giving me this error: `ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit` is this because of any duplicate in the file?

Comment: @Abhis - It means there are duplicated datetimes. So need remove dupes by `df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('nav_date')`